# D3 Map projection for Europe like Albert USA

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm quite new to D3.js, up to now I've been able to find an answer to all my problems searching here and there, but I haven't found anything for this one, yet.

There's this very nice map projection for USA that shows Alaska and other places moved to the bottom of the map (albers USA).

I'm making several choropleth maps for nuts 2010 europe (the official way europe is divided in smaller region), and I will need to do something similar, showing Guyana, and some islands groups in different rectangles to the bottom or to the right of the map.
Kind of like this: http://whs.moodledo.co.uk/file.php/1378/Europe_Quality_of_Life/GDP_Europe_2004.png

Plus I would need to show a zoom of Malta, so that you can actually see what color the choropleth is for it.

This is an example of my paths, extracted from a geojson, once they've been computed by q3.js:

```
....
<path id="ITI3" class="nut cat2" d="M519.439374985861..."></path>
<path id="ITI4" class="nut cat2" d="M496.3654726267817,575.02..."></path>
<path id="LT00" class="nut cat1" d="..."></path>
<path id="MT00" class="nut cat4" d="Z"></path>
<path id="LV00" class="nut cat1" d="M637.95Z"></path><path id="MT00" class="nut cat3" d="M517.0753838465" fill="#000"></path>
...
```

the id for the nuts region I'll need to move and resize are

```
FR91 (south america)
FR92 (south america)
FR93 (south america)
FR94 (somewhere close to madagascar)
MT00 (malta)
PT30
PT20
ES70
```

What do you suggest to do?
Do I need to create several different layers for each of them at creation time,  is it better to take albers USA projection and modify it accordingly or to transform them somehow after the path has been created? Or maybe something else I haven't yet thought about?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the mercator projection. I think that the best option to display other territories, is to make separate charts. You can add groups to the main svg figure and translate them. This article explains how to make maps properly in d3: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/.

Comment: I think I need something more performing than several maps.... especially considering the amount of choropleth I have to prepare. I'm searching for a projection, or a way to modify a projection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't mess around with the actual shape files, just create a new projection. The implementation of Albert USA isn't too tricky:

```
function albersUsa(location) {
  var longitude = location[0],
      latitude = location[1];
  return (latitude > 50 ? alaska
      : longitude < -140 ? hawaii
      : latitude < 21 ? puertoRico
      : lower48)(coordinates);
}
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albersUsa

You should be able to create version for Europe.

Comment: Thank you Adam, that seems like the correct route (if I had enough reputation I'd give you a vote up). Do anybody know if there's any info about how to make a projection anywhere?

Comment: There is a little information here: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geo/projection

You might be better off just reading the source code for Albert USA:https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/geo/albers-usa.js

Full disclosure - I haven't done this before, but it definitely looks doable

Answer (score 0):

If you check this example how to use Albers projection for the Europe, I'm sure you will be able to easily adjust it to your zoom, rotation and boundary preferences:

https://observablehq.com/@toja/five-map-projections-for-europe#_albers

You just need to tweak the parameters in your web page map script (code part copied from above):

```
albers = d3.geoAlbers()
    .rotate([-20.0, 0.0])
    .center([0.0, 52.0])
    .parallels([35.0, 65.0])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(700)
    .precision(.1)
```